# Javascript Caching API Issues

Tags: javascript, caching, cloudflare

I am using worker to do my caching task based on device type because the theme I am using doesn't have a separate mobile cache and also Cloudflare doesn't have device type caching at the server's edge, Therefor I used a worker to do this task. With the normal GET request at first, it shows cache status dynamic after a couple of reloads it shows to hit.

There is also a POST method in the worker code so when the POST request is made then it should make also a GET request so the cache for that product is saved. The problem I am facing with the POST method whenever I publish a product the cache is not re-validated and therefore I am getting an old cache. Even if I purge cache it doesn't re-validate cache or show expire cache, It shows to hit.

I know I am not doing it wrong, I would be very thankful if you can help me, below is the code snippet I am using.

Thank you so much.

```
async function run(event) {
  const { request } = event;

  const cache = caches.default;

  // Read the user agent of the request
  const ua = request.headers.get('user-agent');
  let uaValue;

  if (ua.match(/mobile/i)) {
    uaValue = 'mobile';
  } else {
    uaValue = 'desktop';
  }

  // Construct a new response object which distinguishes the cache key by device
  // type.
  const url = new URL(request.url);
  url.searchParams.set('ua', uaValue);
  const newRequest = new Request(url, request);

  let response = await cache.match(newRequest);
  if (!response) {
    // Use the original request object when fetching the response from the
    // server to avoid passing on the query parameters to our backend.
    response = await fetch(request);
    response = new Response(response.body, response)
    response.headers.append("Cache-Control", "max-age=31536000")

    // Store the cached response with our extended query parameters.
    event.waitUntil(cache.put(newRequest, response.clone()));
  }

  return response;
}

async function sha256(message) {
  // encode as UTF-8
  const msgBuffer = new TextEncoder().encode(message)

  // hash the message
  const hashBuffer = await crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", msgBuffer)

  // convert ArrayBuffer to Array
  const hashArray = Array.from(new Uint8Array(hashBuffer))

  // convert bytes to hex string
  const hashHex = hashArray.map(b => ("00" + b.toString(16)).slice(-2)).join("")
  return hashHex
}

async function handlePostRequest(event) {
  const request = event.request
  const body = await request.clone().text()
  const hash = await sha256(body)
  const cacheUrl = new URL(request.url)

  // Store the URL in cache by prepending the body's hash
  cacheUrl.pathname = "/posts" + cacheUrl.pathname + hash

  // Convert to a GET to be able to cache
  const cacheKey = new Request(cacheUrl.toString(), {
    headers: request.headers,
    method: "GET",
  })

  const cache = caches.default

  // Find the cache key in the cache
  let response = await cache.match(cacheKey)

  // Otherwise, fetch response to POST request from origin
  if (!response) {
    response = await fetch(request)
    event.waitUntil(cache.put(cacheKey, response.clone()))
  }
  return response
}

addEventListener("fetch", event => {
  try {
    const request = event.request
    if (request.method.toUpperCase() === "POST")
      return event.respondWith(handlePostRequest(event))
    return event.respondWith(run(event))
  } catch (e) {
    return event.respondWith(new Response("Error thrown " + e.message))
  }
})
```